# How to enable additional audit logging?

Tags: centos, linux-kernel, linux-audit

We use Auditd to monitor specific changes on Linux systems. Majority of our rules come from CIS Benchmark guidelines and then few are added specifically to monitor certain command executions.

We have only seen the following record types so far:

```
PATH, SYSCALL, CWD, AVC, EXECVE, USER_CMD, USER_LOGIN, USER_AUTH
```

As per the [this](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security_Guide/sec-Audit_Record_Types.html) link, there are several interesting types which would be crucial to monitor. Few which seem important in our environment are

```
KERNEL, ADD_USER, ADD_GROUP, MAC_STATUS, NETFILTER_CFG.
```

Based on the rules mentioned below, can anyone assist in figuring out if these events are being monitored and just haven't been triggered yet, or is the current ruleset incomplete?

```
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S adjtimex -S settimeofday -k time-change    
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S clock_settime -k time-change  
-w /etc/localtime -p wa -k time-change  
-w /etc/group -p wa -k identity  
-w /etc/passwd -p wa -k identity  
-w /etc/gshadow -p wa -k identity  
-w /etc/shadow -p wa -k identity  
-w /etc/security/opasswd -p wa -k identity  
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S sethostname -S setdomainname -k system-locale
-w /etc/issue -p wa -k system-locale  
-w /etc/issue.net -p wa -k system-locale  
-w /etc/hosts -p wa -k system-locale  
-w /etc/sysconfig/network -p wa -k system-locale  
-w /etc/selinux/ -p wa -k MAC-policy  
-w /var/log/faillog -p wa -k logins  
-w /var/log/lastlog -p wa -k logins  
-w /var/log/tallylog -p wa -k logins  
-w /var/log/btmp -p wa -k session  
-w /var/run/utmp -p wa -k session  
-w /var/log/wtmp -p wa -k session  
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S chmod -S fchmod -S fchmodat -F auid>=500 -F auid!=4294967295 -k perm_mod  
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S chown -S fchown -S fchownat -S lchown -F auid>=500 -F auid!=4294967295 -k perm_mod  
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S setxattr -S lsetxattr -S fsetxattr -S removexattr -S lremovexattr -S fremovexattr -F auid>=500 -F auid!=4294967295 -k perm_mod  
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S creat -S open -S openat -S truncate -S ftruncate -F exit=-EACCES -F auid>=500 -F auid!=4294967295 -k access  
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S creat -S open -S openat -S truncate -S ftruncate -F exit=-EPERM -F auid>=500 -F auid!=4294967295 -k access  
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S mount -F auid>=500 -F auid!=4294967295 -k mounts  
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S unlink -S unlinkat -S rename -S renameat -F auid>=500 -F auid!=4294967295 -k delete  
-w /etc/sudoers -p wa -k scope  
-w /var/log/sudo.log -p wa -k actions  
-w /sbin/insmod -p x -k modules  
-w /sbin/rmmod -p x -k modules  
-w /sbin/modprobe -p x -k modules  
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S init_module -S delete_module -k modules  
-a always,exit -F path=/bin/su -F perm=x -F auid>=500 -F auid!=4294967295 -k privileged  
-a always,exit -F path=/bin/ping6 -F perm=x -F auid>=500 -F auid!=4294967295 -k privileged  
-a always,exit -F path=/sbin/unix_chkpwd -F perm=x -F auid>=500 -F auid!=4294967295 -k privileged  
-a always,exit -F path=/sbin/pam_timestamp_check -F perm=x -F auid>=500 -F auid!=4294967295 -k privileged  
-a always,exit -F path=/sbin/mount.nfs -F perm=x -F auid>=500 -F auid!=4294967295 -k privileged
```

Few command specific rules:

```
-a exit,always -F arch=b64 -S execve -F path=/bin/rm  
-a exit,always -F arch=b64 -S execve -F path=/bin/chmod  
-a exit,always -F arch=b64 -S execve -F path=/bin/chgrp  
-a exit,always -F arch=b64 -S execve -F path=/bin/chown
```

Data we are currently getting from above rules is extremely helpful and valuable. How to take audit logging a step further?